# Unable to get references of the elements which are defined inside ng-switch/ng-include condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a wierd issue with angularjs switch condition. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div data-component="dropdown" ng-switch on="1">

   <div class="btn-group " ng-switch-when="1">
           <input id="inputField" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
            <button id="inputButton" class="btn i " data-toggle="dropdown">
           <i class="icon"></i>
          </button>
           <ul class="menu">
          </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to get the reference of input field as `$("#inputField");` Executing this command in Chrome's console and gives output as [].

On removing ng-switch i am getting the expected output as `[<input id="inputField" type="text" readonly="readonly" />]`.

I am also facing same issue with ng-include.

Comment: Stop using jQuery to look up selectors on your Angular app. That's what directives are for.

Comment: so the other way round is using angular.element(). is it so? to lookup for an elemnt

Comment: No, angular.element is just a jQuery lite wrapper. Make your #inputButton a directive or put a directive on it with an attribute or class restriction and then `element` will be that node.